# XSL template not being applied

Tags: templates, xslt

Following is some XSL that I'm editing. I had to add code to account for html tables and cannot figure out why the templates under [CITATIONS] are being applied, but those under [TABLES] are not. The code for [CITATIONS] was there and working before I started. The code for [TABLES] I stole from another part of the application and where it does work just fine. Does anything here stand out to anyone? Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- Common template for procedure sub-sections. -->
<xsl:template match="th:section" priority="1" mode="procedures">
    <div id="tab{position()}">
        <xsl:if test="count(*//th:figure) gt 0">
            <hr/>
            <div class="carrousel floatbox">

            <!-- LOTS OF CODE HERE. -->

            </div>
            <hr/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:next-match/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- [TABLES] Table templates not being applied. -->
<xsl:template match="th:table" mode="procedures">
<table border="1">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="th:thead">
<thead>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</thead>
</xsl:template>
<!-- [More table templates follow here to handle table body and footer. None are being applied.] -->

<!-- [CITATIONS] These templates are being applied. -->
<xsl:template match="th:section[@type = 'literature']" mode="procedures">
    <ol class="litrefs">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="refs"/>
    </ol>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="th:litref" mode="refs">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="refs"/>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
<!-- [More templates follow here to handle citations. No problems here.] -->
```

Comment: Are there any _other_ templates that might match the same nodes?  I'd try running it with tracing (e.g. use the `-T` option to the command-line Saxon 9 processor) to see exactly which templates are firing when.

Comment: I don't believe so. I've done a search for "table" in the two relevant .xsl files (this one and the one import file) and there are no other templates for th:table.

Comment: Well, I did find saxon on the drive, but perhaps there is another class doing the transform. I tried to run a transform from the command line and got a NoClassDefFoundError Exception for net.sf.saxon.Transform.

Comment: ARGH. Finally got all the paths corrected to run the command and I've got a bunch of other paths to fix in the one import file, but I may be on to something. Thanks.

Comment: OK, so this is the error I got, which I assume means a bad character in the XML:

Error
  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Inv
alid byte 1
  of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
Transformation failed: Run-time errors were reported

Comment: You have the `mode` attribute set on templates, but you have calls to `<xsl:apply-templates/>` that do not specify the mode.  For example, if a `th:table` can occur within a `th:section`, do the `apply-templates` calls within the section template specify the `procedures` mode?  You also have `refs` mode templates.  I think you are losing track of your modes.

Comment: Well, there was a "catch-all" template that was overriding my table templates. Got it now. Thanks.